# Integrate bootstrap theme with nuxt.js project

Tags: config, nuxt.js

I just started a new project and am working with a bootstrap theme that I would like integrated with my Nuxt.js project.

I believe I have loaded all of the css asset files properly, although I am trying to figure out how to properly add the JS files.

I have tried loading the script source files in `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: './assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/jquery.knob.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/jquery.waypoints.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/wow.min.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/smoothscroll.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/gmaps.js'},
      { src: './assets/js/custom.js'},
      { src: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'}
    ]
  },
...
```

and I have also tried adding theme directly within my `index.vue` file like this:

```
<script>
// import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    // Logo
  },
  head () {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: '/assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/jquery.knob.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/jquery.waypoints.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/wow.min.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/smoothscroll.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/gmaps.js'},
        { src: '/assets/js/custom.js'},
        { src: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I've tried starting the paths with `~/`, `/` as well as `./`

The issue is that these source files are not being found with the declared path.

[image: bootstrap theme integration with nuxt console err]

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: its bad idea to integrate jquery into nuxt. it will be point of problem and its not recommended

Comment: thanks for letting me know! I was not aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the assets folder is the best place for the scripts because webpack is going to process that folder. For my scripts I use the **static** folder, you only need **/** for the route, Ex:

```
script: [{ src: "/highlight.pack.js" }, { src: "/animate.js" }]
```

Or you can use CDN addresses for the most common libraries. You will only need the URL. Ex:

```
 export default {
      head: {
        script: [
          { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' }
        ],

      }
    }
```

Remember also that you can integrate Bootstrap in NUXT with no need of Jquery thanks to [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/).

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, I will try this! Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!